# Git crashes while installing libraries

Tags: git, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm starting using Doctrine (2.0.0 Beta5). I've tried to install doctrine-fixtures and DoctrineFixturesBundle by adding

```
[doctrine-fixtures]     
    git=https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures.git
    target=/

[DoctrineFixturesBundle] 
    git=https://github.com/symfony/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle
```

to my deps file. Then I've launched a command like this

```
php bin/vendors install
```

Here's an error

```
> Installing/Updating doctrine-fixtures
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent )
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
> Installing/Updating DoctrineFixturesBundle
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent )
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

And here's the whole output

```
orson@nautilus:~/public_html/elka$ php bin/vendors install
> Installing/Updating symfony
Cloning into /home/orson/public_html/elka/vendor/symfony...
remote: Counting objects: 85579, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (27829/27829), done.
remote: Total 85579 (delta 53190), reused 79292 (delta 47957)
Receiving objects: 100% (85579/85579), 13.37 MiB | 942 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (53190/53190), done.
HEAD is now at c62724b revert to BETA5 for a moment
> Installing/Updating twig
Cloning into /home/orson/public_html/elka/vendor/twig...
remote: Counting objects: 6532, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1770/1770), done.
remote: Total 6532 (delta 4317), reused 6213 (delta 4042)
Receiving objects: 100% (6532/6532), 890.70 KiB | 316 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4317/4317), done.
HEAD is now at a12aec3 added Twig_Error::getRawMessage()
> Installing/Updating monolog
Cloning into /home/orson/public_html/elka/vendor/monolog...
remote: Counting objects: 1019, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (406/406), done.
remote: Total 1019 (delta 545), reused 972 (delta 506)
Receiving objects: 100% (1019/1019), 127.51 KiB | 38 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (545/545), done.
HEAD is now at ff6d7fc Adjusted tests
> Installing/Updating doctrine-common
Cloning into /home/orson/public_html/elka/vendor/doctrine-common...
remote: Counting objects: 55356, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13790/13790), done.
remote: Total 55356 (delta 39096), reused 55271 (delta 39022)
Receiving objects: 100% (55356/55356), 15.05 MiB | 943 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (39096/39096), done.
HEAD is now at 0ba250a Added private to ignored annotations.
> Installing/Updating doctrine-dbal
Cloning into /home/orson/public_html/elka/vendor/doctrine-dbal...
remote: Counting objects: 56825, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14335/14335), done.
remote: Total 56825 (delta 40125), reused 56605 (delta 39930)
Receiving objects: 100% (56825/56825), 15.45 MiB | 942 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (40125/40125), done.
HEAD is now at cfcad35 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'
> Installing/Updating doctrine
Cloning into /home/orson/public_html/elka/vendor/doctrine...
remote: Counting objects: 60840, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (15361/15361), done.
remote: Total 60840 (delta 42779), reused 60439 (delta 42432)
Receiving objects: 100% (60840/60840), 15.82 MiB | 940 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (42779/42779), done.
HEAD is now at 98bc3c4 Merge pull request #74 from mridgway/DDC-1209
> Installing/Updating swiftmailer
Cloning into /home/orson/public_html/elka/vendor/swiftmailer...
remote: Counting objects: 9171, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3093/3093), done.
remote: Total 9171 (delta 5245), reused 9059 (delta 5148)
Receiving objects: 100% (9171/9171), 4.94 MiB | 749 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5245/5245), done.
HEAD is now at d4e5e63 removed the Blackhole plugin (as it short-circuits the beforeSendPerformed event, other plugins are not calling and sendPerformed is never called)
> Installing/Updating assetic
Cloning into /home/orson/public_html/elka/vendor/assetic...
remote: Counting objects: 4039, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1426/1426), done.
remote: Total 4039 (delta 2389), reused 3813 (delta 2194)
Receiving objects: 100% (4039/4039), 465.67 KiB | 286 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2389/2389), done.
HEAD is now at 2b53d87 changed type hint to interface
> Installing/Updating twig-extensions
Cloning into /home/orson/public_html/elka/vendor/twig-extensions...
remote: Counting objects: 224, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (158/158), done.
remote: Total 224 (delta 78), reused 89 (delta 17)
Receiving objects: 100% (224/224), 31.55 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (78/78), done.
HEAD is now at 6b0cc16 Fixes issue #7
> Installing/Updating metadata
Cloning into /home/orson/public_html/elka/vendor/metadata...
remote: Counting objects: 88, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (72/72), done.
remote: Total 88 (delta 42), reused 8 (delta 3)
Unpacking objects: 100% (88/88), done.
HEAD is now at aa04872 added a test for cache invalidation
> Installing/Updating SensioFrameworkExtraBundle
Cloning into /home/orson/public_html/elka/vendor//bundles/Sensio/Bundle/FrameworkExtraBundle...
remote: Counting objects: 788, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (384/384), done.
remote: Total 788 (delta 443), reused 714 (delta 379)
Receiving objects: 100% (788/788), 93.92 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (443/443), done.
HEAD is now at d529f70 Better default route name formatter to follow conventions. The words "action", "bundle", "controller" can be part of the name and should not be always removed.
> Installing/Updating JMSSecurityExtraBundle
Cloning into /home/orson/public_html/elka/vendor//bundles/JMS/SecurityExtraBundle...
remote: Counting objects: 1008, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (429/429), done.
remote: Total 1008 (delta 515), reused 978 (delta 485)
Receiving objects: 100% (1008/1008), 159.25 KiB | 253 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (515/515), done.
HEAD is now at 5676f8d updated to latest changes
> Installing/Updating WebConfiguratorBundle
Cloning into /home/orson/public_html/elka/vendor//bundles/Symfony/Bundle/WebConfiguratorBundle...
remote: Counting objects: 220, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (114/114), done.
remote: Total 220 (delta 113), reused 209 (delta 102)
Receiving objects: 100% (220/220), 35.12 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (113/113), done.
HEAD is now at 301419e updated for the latest Symfony
> Installing/Updating AsseticBundle
Cloning into /home/orson/public_html/elka/vendor//bundles/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle...
remote: Counting objects: 1474, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (449/449), done.
remote: Total 1474 (delta 878), reused 1444 (delta 848)
Receiving objects: 100% (1474/1474), 202.78 KiB | 177 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (878/878), done.
HEAD is now at 6d597c4 [AsseticBundle] fixed unit tests
> Installing/Updating doctrine-fixtures
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent )
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
> Installing/Updating DoctrineFixturesBundle
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent )
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into /home/orson/public_html/elka/web//bundles/framework
Installing assets for Acme\DemoBundle into /home/orson/public_html/elka/web//bundles/acmedemo
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle into /home/orson/public_html/elka/web//bundles/webprofiler
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\WebConfiguratorBundle into /home/orson/public_html/elka/web//bundles/symfonywebconfigurator
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[doctrine-fixtures]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures.git

[DoctrineFixturesBundle]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle
```

Try this.
I think, that you didn't write git address right.